# Pick the right config file

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

I have created two files in my `src/main/resources` folder

```
application-dev.conf
```

which contains

```
dev {
  oracle {
    host = "foo"
  }
}
```

and 
    application-qa.conf

which contains

```
qa {
  oracle {
    host = "bar"
  }
}
```

I read this configuration with the following code

```
val env = args.lift(0).getOrElse("dev")
val parsedConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(s"src/main/resources/application-${env}.conf"))
val conf = ConfigFactory.load(parsedConfig)
val config = conf.getConfig(env)
println(config.getString("oracle.host"))
```

Everything works great at development time and I am able to read the right configuration file based on the environment specified. If I don't specify anything then development is chosen.

However now when I package my jar file as an assembly using `sbt assembly` and now try to run my application from the command line `java -jar ./target/MyApplication.jar`

I get an error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'dev'
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:152)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:170)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:184)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:189)
```

My objective is that I should have multiple configuration files and I should be able to choose between them at dev time and also when the application is packaged as a jar.

Based on the suggestion below I modified my code to

```
val env = args.lift(0).getOrElse("dev")
val parsedConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(getClass.getResource(s"/application-${env}.conf").toURI))
val conf = ConfigFactory.load(parsedConfig)
val config = conf.getConfig(env)
println(config.getString("oracle.host"))
```

works in dev, but when I try to run my assembly it throws an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:418)
```

Answer (score 1):

The config file is not in `src/main/resources` in your assembly. It usually is at the root of the classpath (unless you have configured the plugin to package it somewhere else).

Try using like below.

```
ConfigFactory.load(s"application-${env}.conf")
```

This loads the config file from the classpath.

Comment: Are you sure the config file is in the root of the classpath in your assembly? If not, you have to add the path accordingly.

Comment: yes its in the root. I did a `jar -tvf ` on the jar and confirmed.